# How to get value from strings.xml to arraylist

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, key-value

I have the following code:

```
package com.sample.app;

import android.content.res.Resources;

import java.util.ArrayList;




public class Content {

    public static ArrayList<String> Names;
    public static ArrayList<String> NamesSub;
    public static ArrayList<String> Images;
    public static ArrayList<String> Wallpaper;
    public static ArrayList<String> Audio;
    public static ArrayList<String> BIG_Images;
    public static ArrayList<String> Sub_heading;
    public static ArrayList<String> Description;


    Content(){
        this.Names = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.NamesSub = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.Sub_heading = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.Images = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.Wallpaper = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.BIG_Images = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.Audio = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.Description = new ArrayList<String>();

        this.Description.add(0, "Long description");
        this.Description.add(1, "");
        this.Description.add(2, "");

    }

}
```

And have a too long description for `ArrayList`. when I paste the description it gave me

> error: constant string too long

error. After that i tried setting values from `strings.xml`. I am using this code for getting values:

```
this.Description.add(0,String.valueOf(R.string.descvalue));
```

But when I run the app it prints numbers like this `2131689519` not my values.

After that i tried `string-array`

```
<string-array name="descvalue">
    <item>too long value</item>
</string-array>
```

And in the java file, I tried getting values with this code:

```
this.Description.add(0, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.descvalue)[0]);
```

But when I run the app it's crashing.

So what should I do in this case? Thanks.

Comment: The length of constant strings in java is limited to 64K during compile time.

Answer (score 1):

"error: constant string too long"

for this, you can go with Text class

```
Text text = new Text("foo");
String s = text.getText(); 
text.setText(s);
```

Comment: can you show me an example? i am sorry but i am newbie at java

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
this.Description.add(0,String.valueOf(R.string.descvalue));
```

With

```
this.Description.add(0,getString(R.string.descvalue));
```

but `getString()` needs a `context`.

Comment: getString turning red, i think i should add some codes right? how can i add context

Comment: you can obtain a context object from activity or fragment or application class depending on where you will put your code.